# BeautifulSoup find text in specific tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With BeautifulSoup, I'm trying to print text that's inside a specific tag, the problem is the text I want to print is inside a tag within a `<tr>` tag and the web page has 30 `<tr>` tags. 
The text I need to print is in the second `<td>` tag inside the 19th occurrence of the `<tr>` tag.
It looks like this:

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="QL">Text1</td>
    <td class="QL">Text2</td>
    <td class="QL">Text3</td>
</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

I want to print Text2.

Here's my try at it:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = 'http://google.com'
page = urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find("td", {"class": "QL"}):
    print(link)
```

As it is, it's printing the first occurrence of the `<td class="QL">` tag. How do I make it print the text inside the 19th occurrence of that tag and without having Text1 and Text3 print as well?

Comment: You need `soup.findAll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know the exact positions of the tags you want to find, you can use `find_all()` which returns a list and then get the tag from the required index.

In this case, (19th `<tr>` and 2nd `<td>`) use this:

```
result = soup.find_all('tr')[18].find_all('td')[1].text
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine.
However, I'm now using it to get the text from multiple pages that are mostly structured the same way but every now and then there's a page where the text isn't in the same spot and it returns an index error `IndexError: list index out of range`.
The index error prevents the code to keep going, how can I avoid that (and return a blank result instead for example)?

Comment: Use `try-except`. If you are unaware of this concept, just Google it. you'll understand it better.

Comment: Thank you, I googled it and successfully implemented it, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` with `find_all`:

```
result = [a.text for i, a in enumerate(soup.find_all("td", {"class": "QL"}), start=1) if i == 19][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be this.

```
result = [ x.text for x in soup.select('tr > td:nth-of-type(2)')]
```